# Connection refused after few seconds of launch In Internet explorer in karate

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I've configured iedriver in karate DSL. and after launching the ie and navigated to the Url the browser is not maximizing using driver.maximize()

also getting the below error after launching the browser in few seconds. and driver doesn't quit automatically

ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:5555 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, http call failed after 4088 milliseconds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhXTX.png)

Comment: Hi, This is a problem in IE and the question marked as referred here is for chrome